# How to bulk update then save images in wordpress posts

Tags: images

I've got a site with 3000+ posts with images in them.
I need to bulk update all images - with no changes - then save the post to trigger the captions to show up properly.

Right now the site is trying to force captions, but shows an 'Undefined' if the caption was blank. But as soon as you go into a post, click on the image to edit it, do nothing and just click Update, then Update the post, the Undefined message goes away.

So just looking for a way to trigger that caption by updating the image and saving, but didn't want to do it to the 3000+ posts.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you call the caption of the image ? how is this rendered in HTML ?

Comment: This sounds related to either your theme or a plugin. WP by default only adds a native "caption" if you have filled out the text - not if you leave that blank when you upload the media. If you can provide some code, even the HTML output where it's showing Undefined, that may help everyone figure out where this is coming from.